# Filter a nested collections with LINQ "Include"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I searched online for a long time, but I couldn't really get a straight answer to this. How would I use `Include` to load a nested collection using `Where` to filter it? Let's say, for instance, that I want to include all the `CartItems` that are not disabled:

```
var myCart = _dbContext.Carts
                 .Include(cart => cart.CartShippingBoxes
                     .Select(cartShippingBox => cartShippingBox.CartItems
                         .Where(cartItem => !cartItem.IsDisabled))); // This doesn't work
```

Comment: What about you try to apply the Where first. before all the includes. And you have two redundant includes in your code. Drop one of them.

Comment: I am wondering why you want to filter it in the `include`. In SQL terms it is like having a sub query within the `FROM` clause which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why would I return a huge collection when I only need a small part of it?

Comment: Do you want to do this? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#applying-filters-when-explicitly-loading-related-entities

Comment: Also in the same link it is mentioned that it is not possible to filter includes

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var carts = _dbContext.CartShippingBoxes
                 .Include(item => item.Cart)
                 // .ThenInclude(cart => cart.A)
                         .Where(cartItem => !cartItem.IsDisabled))
                  Select(s=> s.Cart).ToList();
```

Or use overload of `Include` that takes parameter of type `string` like:

```
.Include("Cart").Include("Cart.CollectionA").Include("Cart.CollectionB")
.Include("Cart.CollectionZ")
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me in production, I need to start from `_dbContext.Carts` because the query is actually much more complicated and has various `Include` related to other objects and collection of the `Cart` itself

Comment: @tocqueville You can include want you want with `ThenInclude` after `Include(item => item.Cart)` .

Comment: @tocqueville You also can use overload of `Include` that takes parameter of type `string` .

Comment: I'm using EF6, I cannot use ThenInclude

Comment: @tocqueville Intellisense will only give you the `Include(string path)` version of the method.